# Release и Debug компиляция в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Вопрос интересного характера, почему один и тот-же код после компиляции в Debug работает нормально, а после компиляции Release не работает так как положено.

Comment: Без подробностей невозможно ответить на этот вопрос =\

Comment: @LevBazdyrev Основная причина - это неопределенное поведение вашей программы, связанное с ее некорректностью. Иногда в редких случаях причиной является баг компилятора.

Comment: Разобрался... Всем спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В отладочном режиме в объектный файл помещается много лишней для боевой работы программы информации. В частности, может быть ситуация, когда в программе используется чтение неинициализированной памяти. Такое действие приводит в общем случае к чтению мусора. Однако в отладочном режиме вся такая память может быть неявно (из-за выключенных оптимизаций, например) инициализирована чем-то конкретным, например, нулями.

В таком случае элементарный код вида:

```
int k;
std::cout << k << '\n'
```

может выдавать либо `0`, либо любое случайное число.

Т.о. если логика программы зависит от чтения неинициализированной памяти, поведение программы в отладочном и релизном режимах может отличаться.

Comment: Приму Ваш Ваше сообщение как ответ, информация полезна. Но в моём случае это была просто банальная невнимательность, в плане параметров в файле настройки!

Comment: @LevBazdyrev что за параметры?

Comment: в ини файлах парметры обновил (дебаг режим) а в релизе забыл. А программа от этих параметров отталкивается.