# SIGSEGV при сборке приложения в режиме релиза?

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

Проблема заключается в том что я не могу понять почему я получаю ошибку SIGSEGV.
Если я собираю в режиме Debug программа работает, все хорошо, все как задумал. А вот если компилю в релиз моде, то я при работе получаю ошибку SIGSEGV.

Может я неправильно объявил двумерный массив?

Приложу то в чем я подозреваю проблему:

Вот класс mainwindow.h

```
// mainwindow.h
private:
int gameData[4][4];

public:
int getGameData(int x, int y);
int setGameData(int x, int y, int val);
```

Вот класс mainwindow.cpp

```
// mainwindow.cpp
void MainWindow::moveLeft(){

bool move = false;

// Сдвиг в влево
for(int x =0; x<4; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<4; y++){
        if(MainWindow::getGameData(x, y) == 0){
            for (int i = y; i < 4; i++){
                if(MainWindow::getGameData(x, i) != 0){
                    MainWindow::setGameData(x, y, MainWindow::getGameData(x, i));
                    MainWindow::setGameData(x, i, 0);
                    move = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for(int x = 0; x<4; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y<3; y++){
        if(MainWindow::getGameData(x, y) == MainWindow::getGameData(x, y+1)){
            MainWindow::setGameData(x, y, MainWindow::getGameData(x, y)*2);
            MainWindow::scoreValuePlus(MainWindow::getGameData(x, y));
            MainWindow::setGameData(x, y+1, 0);
            move = true;
        }

        for(int x =0; x<4; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<4; y++){
                if(MainWindow::getGameData(x, y) == 0){
                    for (int i = y; i < 4; i++){
                        if(MainWindow::getGameData(x, i) != 0){
                            MainWindow::setGameData(x, y, MainWindow::getGameData(x, i));
                            MainWindow::setGameData(x, i, 0);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(MainWindow::getGameData(x, y) == 0){
            ui->gameGrid->item(x, y)->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, QVariant(""));;
        }
        else {
            ui->gameGrid->item(x, y)->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, QVariant(MainWindow::getGameData(x, y)));
        }
    }
}

if(move == true){
    MainWindow::generateCell(true);
    MainWindow::moveValuePlus();
}
```

Вот весь листинг кода:

[mainwindow.h](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6b5002b1ae7cbf10faf30d4ee6ea5191)
[mainwindow.cpp](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/16198dd29f39b58bfbce41a07b2def55)

Comment: Добавьте проверку в `get|setGameData` что нет выхода за пределы `[0..4)` для индексов. И поставьте точку останова. Возможно, найдете ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо за идею. А вообще, с чем может быть связана эта проблема? (Я говорю про то что программа в режиме debug работает хорошо, а в deploy — нет).

Comment: Посмотрите [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476082/release-%d0%b8-debug-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-qt) вопрос.

Comment: Скорее всего, в коде есть undefined behaviour (например, выход за границы массива). Такой код имеет прав себя вести вообще как угодно, и обычно чем сильнее настройки оптимизации, тем более странно будет вести себя код.

Comment: @VladD Прошу прощение, «и обычно чем сильнее настройки оптимизации» чего? То есть оптимизации моего кода?

Comment: @ladone: Да. Чем больше оптимизаций вы включите при компиляции, тем больше возможностей будет для оптимизатора соптимизировать код, в частности, воспользовавшись undefined behaviour для этого.

Comment: Одна из ошибок "выход за пределы" на 415 строке. Обращение к индексу `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения вопроса помогла дополнительная проверка при сложении чисел.

```
for(int x = 0; x<4; x++){
    for(int y = 3; y>=0; y--){
       if(y>0 && MainWindow::getGameData(x, y) == MainWindow::getGameData(x, y-1))
```

Всем спасибо большое!